# Fundamental group from triangulation

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, fundamental-groups

How do I calculate the fundamental group of surface if I have been given it in triangulated form.

I have attached an example triangulation

[image: triangulation]

I think I may have to simplify it further to a tree and look at remaining 1-simplicies as generators of the fundamental group

But am having trouble in getting there

Comment: Try using the Seifert-van Kampen theorem. Choose as your open sets a disk around the center of the square and the complement of the center. (Note this doesn't depend on the triangulation).

Comment: As an alternative to "simplifying it further to a tree", instead choose a maximal tree in the 2-skeleton. Then, as you say, look at the remaining 1-simplices as generators of the fundamental group.