# How do I triangulate a Tetrahedron?

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, triangulation

I have a question in triangulating a Tetrahedron. Is it correct that it works as follows (the green arrows should point in the direction of the orientation):[image]

And if yes for what can I use this now?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use this now to understand the [Unshellable Triangulation of a Tetrahedron](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjt6aPGwt71AhXQ0KQKHZP5BcEQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fbull%2F1958-64-03%2FS0002-9904-1958-10168-8%2FS0002-9904-1958-10168-8.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3uQmEicmSJvG7GlnGS2guO) by Rudin, or to compute the [Euler characteristic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084195/classifying-surface-given-a-triangulation).

Comment: Aha so here the tetrahedron was only chosen because we had it in the lecture, but when we consider an arbitrary surface can we say something abut the fundamental group for example while looking at such a triangulation?

Comment: Like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666146/fundamental-group-from-triangulation)? Have a look at MSE here, they have a lot on this topic (alone the hits from Lee Mosher's answers are several hundred ones).

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes exaclty with the euler characteristic, for what is this used? so We had soemthing about classification of compact oriented surfaces, but is this then a triangulation because there we only used some lettes $aba^{-1}...$ but I don't see triangles

Comment: I see [triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666146/fundamental-group-from-triangulation) quite clearly :)

Comment: so no sorry I mean while using fultons book we had something called the normal form there I don't see some triangulations. And in addition how can I then compute the fundamental group of the exercise you sent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133700/discussion-between-aprozz-and-dietrich-burde).

Comment: It would be nice if we could discuss this quickly

Comment: Your question asking what this can be used for is, well, a gigantic question. Suffice it to say that the entire subject of algebraic topology is founded upon triangulations, and with the tiniest bit of patience and perseverance in your studies you will quickly see multiple applications of triangulations.

Comment: In general, asking one question after another in your post and your comments is a bad use of this site. You should restrict your post to a single, *answerable* question.

Comment: so sorry no my question was only if now I know the triangulation for example in my tetrahedron: $4$ faces, $4$ vertices, $6$ edges, then I know the euler characteristic $\chi=4-6+4=2$ right? But then I also know that the genus has the formula $2-2g=\chi$ so I know that $g=0$ this means that it has no whole (which is clear right)? but what can I say more about this, maybe with the fundamental group? I'm sorry to ask such stupid questions but the problem is that we have discussed triangulation and eulercharakterisazion in the last 45 minutes, and it will be a part of the exam